# Google Chrome crashes, doesn't recognize a variable as the name of a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

the following code works perfect of Firefox but crashes on Chrome, with the following error: Uncaught TypeError: Property 'pos' of object [object Object] is not a function

Here is the code, with comments:

```
var CantidadMenu = $('div[class^=container_menu_]').length;
var position = $("#menu_unidades").position();
var IzAdd = 0;
var w = $("#menu_unidades").width();
var h = $("#menu_unidades").height();
for (i=0;i<CantidadMenu;i++){
    var pos = 'pos'+(i+1); //I create a variable that will hold a string like: pos1,pos2...
    IzAdd = IzAdd+25;
    function pos(div){ //on this line I use the variable I created, which crashes on Chrome
        var estilo1 = $(div).css({'left':IzAdd+25,'top':position.top+(IzAdd-25)});
        return estilo1;
    }
    pos('.container_menu_'+(i+1));
    $('.container_menu_'+(i+1)).css({'z-index':297+i,'width':w,'height':h});
}
```

Comment: First of all - that's not a crash - that's a typeerror. Second of all, the bug is not in this script here. It's somewhere where you do `obj["pos"]` or `obj.pos` or `obj[x]` where `x === "pos"`. Not here.

Comment: Moreover, the code above seems pretty broken to me. Why do you have sequential classes with `".container_menu_"+i`? The correct solution would be to learn about arrays and use them instead. I think that'd make your life so much easier..

Comment: Thanks for replying @BenjaminGruenbaum the whole code is already there. I create the 'pos' variable on: var pos = 'pos'+(i+1);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`function pos(div)` is the same as `var pos = function(div)...` (except the former is defined at the parse-time, and the latter at the run-time, but that's irrelevant for your code), so if you expected by defining that `pos = 'pos1';`, for example, you'd get `function pos(div)` to become `function pos1(div)`, *it won't*.

It will just overwrite the `pos` variable, and it will no longer be a string, but a function.

To fix your code, write a single function at the top of your code, outside of the for loop, add another parameter to it (`IzAdd`) and make sure you fix the function calls appropriately.

The function should look something like this:

```
function pos(div, IzAdd){
    return $(div).css({'left':IzAdd+25,'top':position.top+(IzAdd-25)});
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Shomz, I put the function on top of the loop as you suggested. I didn't really have to create multiple 'pos' functions, just change their parameter.

Comment: Glad you got it working! Btw. I meant you should put the function outside of the loop - no need to re-declarate it on every iteration.

Answer (score 2):

Here you define a function named pos:

```
function pos(div){ //on this line I use the variable I created, which crashes on Chrome
    var estilo1 = $(div).css({'left':IzAdd+25,'top':position.top+(IzAdd-25)});
    return estilo1;
}

console.log(pos) // function ....
```

Here you overwrite it with a string:

```
var pos = 'pos'+(i+1);

console.log(pos) // string....
```

You should name either the function or the string to something else.

PS: I know that in your code the order is reversed, but function declarations are hoisted to the top of the scope, so the JS interpreter "sees" them in the order i wrote them in: first function, then the string.

PSS: The crash is actually on this line:

```
pos('.container_menu_'+(i+1));
```